# Computer will freeze/ lock up after doing relatively stressful things

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, cpu, power-supply, freeze

I'll first start off by saying that the issue GENERALLY doesn't occur unless I'm doing something remotely stressful for my computer. This issue used to occur whenever it felt it was necessary, however has not occurred completely randomly for a while now (thankfully)

My computer's specs:

**CPU**: AMD Phenom II X4 960T
**GPU**: GeForce GTX 760
**Memory**: 16 GB RAM
**Resolution Used**: 1680x1050, 59Hz (strange number for refresh rate?) res is highest for monitor
**Nvidia Driver version**: 331.65
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit)

Sometimes I will be able to go 2-3 games (about an hour, depending) and sometimes it will go maybe one game (20-30 minutes) and then my computer will run sluggishly and leave me unable to do much of anything.

I can sometimes interact with programs at a very basic level (maximizing, minimizing), and I usually cannot close them in any way, not even through Task Manager.

The highest temperature my GPU reaches is **76C**, with the average being around **73C**. During the time the temperatures are around **73C**, my GPU's RAM usage is anywhere between 1250-1300 (out of 2GB).

My CPU's temperature never goes over 60C, thankfully.

The PSU should be fine. It's very mildly dusty but I feel as though that would not be causing this problem... I will clean it out as soon as everything else has been ruled out.
Honestly I have no clue how to test the PSU for problems - same goes for my Motherboard.

I cannot really think of what could be causing these freezes otherwise.

**Event Viewer details**:
EventID: 1 - VDS Basic Provider (I've no clue what this is)
EventID: 3 - Kernel-EventTracing (Again, lost)
EventID: 8003 - bowser (this seems fishy)

and the one critical that I know others have been dealing with as I've browsed some other responses on the web:
EventID: 41 - Kernel-Power

any help to solve this problem would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Wlecome to SuperUser.com.  As-is this question shows a lack of research effort (IMO), and the really doesn't contain a question. "My PSU should be fine", OK, but did you try another, known-good PSU to rule it out? How about Memory tests? Disk checks?  Googling the events you listed?  As best I can tell, so far you just looked at the temperatures, the event logs, and some dust. :)

Comment: ... I cannot even begin to tell you how many topics I've looked through to see if I can solve this issue. As for physically sitting here and switching parts in and out - no - I have not done this because I am unfortunately not capable of spewing money from my pores (yet, anyways ;) so just going out and buying a new PSU when that may not even be the issue would be quite the idiotic action for me to take, IMO. I was hoping to get some further confirmation from someone that may have dealt with such things before and some tips on how to possibly go about things w/o spending money first.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first you make sure if its a software issue or Hardware.. 
Go software troubleshooting first : Its a long list to pin point generic slow down as you posted
could be any one of the installed application or driver may be the culprit.

How old is you Windows installation and if you use it for gaming i suggest you go for a windows re installation after backing up your data Its relatively easy.

If unwilling to format than i suggest go for VHD boot windows 7 without formatting your main installation, i.e Dual boot which you can revert afterwards

Before that i would try running disk clean, disk-check and memtest if not done recently ( may be prime95 test here afterwards)
and i hope you are not overclocking

If you still need to go for a hardware troubleshooting than i suggest you start with processor : 
prime95

Comment: I believe I will leave reformatting for last (or will go for a VHD boot). I just did a disk check (sheesh such a lengthy process. Been a while). Everything checks out fine with the HDD. Good to know that's not the issue. Next up are the motherboard and PSU. Any way to check for PSU/ MOBO instability before I go any further?

Answer (score 0):

After perusing the BF4 Reddit some more, I came across a few people that responded to a post there and they said that they were having the same problem as myself. One of them had the same specs as my rig (CPU, GPU, MOBO), the other did not. I went ahead and assumed that since everything was the same with the one person except for my PSU, I decided to switch it out.

Turns out it was indeed the PSU. I have not had my computer hang up even once since switching the PSU out. Not from BF4, not from anything else.

Thanks for your guys' input! Will definitely come here for help in the future :)

** Turns out the issue was a lack of proper voltage getting to my parts (probably mainly my GPU) and just made my computer run sluggishly until I couldn't do anything.

I had a Diablotek PSU originally... Definitely do not recommend and am going to stay away from Diablotek in the future!